# Where does the water in an egg go on boiling?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, biochemistry, food-chemistry

Our textbook says that boiling an egg causes coagulation and denaturation of the proteins present in it. Where does the water in it disappear?

Comment: Do you mean where does the water inside the egg go? If so, most of it is incorporated in the boiled egg.

Comment: If you are wondering why the egg doesn't blow up when the water expands upon heating to it's boiling point, that's a good question.  That's exactly what would happen if it weren't for a fair-sized air pocket within the egg that compresses during boiling.

Comment: Then again, the egg **does** blow up. Try to heat it in a microwave oven and you'll see.

Comment: even more the egg may crack if over boiled or over heated

Comment: @ToddMinehardt, I want to know what chemically occurs. I know that it gets incorporated in thee boiled egg.

Comment: See my comment [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65743/what-happens-to-the-water-inside-the-egg-when-it-is-boiled).

Comment: The way chemically stays water. The coagulation/denaturation simply leads to less dissolved material and therefore a less fluid egg.