# Why have my recent boiled eggs contain water within the membrane?

Tags: bond, biochemistry, solubility, food-chemistry

My wife recently boiled eggs from the grocery. Every single one of the eggs has contained water with in the membrane where the hollow portion of the egg is normally. I have only seen this if maybe the egg is cracked and exposing the inside of the egg to water. I did read from this question [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65743/what-happens-to-the-water-inside-the-egg-when-it-is-boiled) that the normal water that is inside of the egg is mixed with the broken down proteins of the egg and made into a gelatinous-type structure that is the boiled egg.

My concern is that there is a chemical composition change that happened that is preventing the egg  from doing this. To what end, I have no idea, but it is concerning enough for me to propose this question.

Comment: If it's fresh, then I see no problem. Also Cooking.SE would be more appropriate here.

Comment: Only reason I did it here is the linked question is here as well

Answer (score 0):

> … normal water that is inside of the egg is mixed with the broken down proteins of the egg and made into a gelatinous-type structure

The raw egg white is, aside of dissolved salts and small organic molecules, a colloidal solution of water soluble protein from the albumin protein group. This protein gets denaturated during egg boiling by regrouping its 3D structure, forming wit water a white gel.

I assume the eggs got boiled properly, so the most of egg while formed the gel as usually, save the cavity usually filled by air. I also assume you have excluded possibility of macroscopic or microscopic ruptures, allowing filling it by external water.

The option of changing chemical structure of the egg white is not probable, unless the egg is really spoiled.

The remaining option is the membrane, separating the egg content and the air cavity is corrupted, weakened or more permeable, especially during boiling and increased internal pressure.  This may lead to a semipermeable membrane transfer of the albumin serum – solution of ions and small molecules, but without big molecules as proteins – that may resemble water.